# Focus should be lost when clicking on any other item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am using [angular-ng-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete) library at many places in my project.

But i faced 1 issue recently.

I have 1 button besides the autocomplete textbox. Whenever i select any option i am using it to add in the object.

But, Whenever i type something which is not in the dropdown list. At that time i can't click on the button until i click it twice.

So the 1st click is loosing focus from the autocomplete textbox and 2nd click is actually clicking on that button.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpara6)

Try to type anything which is not in the loaded list. Ex: Test

Than try to click on 'Add' button, You will observe that you need to click twice.

For quick fix, I tried to read the mouseleave event on this ng-autocomplete, But it's also not being triggered whenever we are typing something. We need to loose the focus to make mouseleave works. And it's also not a good solution eitherway!

Any help?

Comment: How about adding the button next to the 'Not found' message? E.g 'Not found, add?'

Comment: @amcquaid If  we insert button next to the 'Not found' message, what if I want to add `Albania` ?

Comment: `Albania` is already present in the list, but I see your point. Maybe a sticky option always at the bottom then, providing it is not a match e.g. `Add {userInput}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
onFocused(e) {
    // do something
    this.auto.close();
}
```

Refer this for more https://github.com/gmerabishvili/angular-ng-autocomplete/issues/50

Comment: Sorry, There is issue. It will remove the suggestions on clicking on the textbox :)